# Are antithetical couplets mostly untranslatable?

Tags: translation

For example,

四品青天褂

六味地黃丸

Or

公門桃李崢嶸日

法國荷蘭比利時

I am not sure if there exists any reasonable translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called 無情對, The sentences don't make sense even in Chinese, therefore, there is no way to translate them into English

> [無情對](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A0%E6%83%85%E5%AF%B9)

> It is a special couplet form, the upper and lower lines are not related to cohesion. But each single "character" in the upper couplet match each single "character" in the lower couplet

Example:

[公 vs. 法] (公 = fair; 法 = law) - both noun related to rule

[門 vs. 國] (門 = school; 國 = nation) - both noun related to gathered people

[桃 vs. 荷] (桃 = peach; 荷 = lotus) - both noun related to plant

[李 vs. 蘭] (李 = plum; 蘭 = lily) - both noun related to plant

[崢 vs. 比] (爭 = fight over; 比 = compete) both verb related to competition

[嶸 vs. 利] (榮 = glory; 利 = profit ) both noun related to success

[日 vs. 時] (日 = day; 時 = hour) both noun related to time

Most importantly, these couplets rhyme in Chinese but won't be in English. That's why you can never translate a 無情對 into any other language

A [question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23510/what-is-the-%E5%B9%B3%E4%BB%84-rule-in-%E7%84%A1%E6%83%85%E5%B0%8D) asked by me related to 無情對

Of course, you can translate them word for word, but the end result will not be coherent sentences and certainly not a couplet anymore.

> 公門桃李崢嶸日 (The day the students of the honorable you shine)

> 法國荷蘭比利時 (France, Netherlands, Belgium)

As for normal couplets, you can translate them into complete sentences, but they will not rhyme and won't be couplets